# Will a Netgear FVS336G VPN Firewall also act as a Router/Internet Gateway?

Tags: router

Will a Netgear FVS336G VPN Firewall also act as a Router/ Internet Gateway? I assume it will, but I am confused by the name of the product.

I am looking to upgrade our consumer grade router at our office with something suitable for a small business. I would also like to have VPN access also.

https://www.netgear.com/business/products/security/FVS336G.aspx#tab-techspecs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

[Source](https://community.netgear.com/t5/VPN-Firewalls/Will-a-Netgear-FVS336G-VPN-Firewall-also-act-as-a-Router/m-p/1322234#M8139) Netgear Community forums.